# ClassCastException when collecting to set

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm experiencing a ClassCastException with the following piece of code.

```java
Set<Long> purchaseIds = confirmationCodeToPurchase
                          .entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                          .map(purchase -> (Long)purchase.getPurchaseId())
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
```

`confirmationCodeToPurchase` is a map from a confirmation code (String) to a Purchase type.

I'm extracting just the values of the map (the purchases), getting the purchaseId of each, and putting them into a set.

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to Purchase
```

and the line at which it errors is the collection line. `.collect(Collectors.toSet()))`

Comment: Unrelated, but why stream of the entry set and map to the value, when you can just stream over the value set?

Comment: @Michael I'm just new to this and didn't know it existed

Comment: show us `confirmationCodeToPurchase` and the `Purchase` class

Comment: [Looks okay to me](https://ideone.com/46ejY3). You have an extra closing parenthesis on the collect line, though

Comment: Are you sure it says: **Long** cannot be cast to Purchase, and **not** the other way round? (Purchase can NOT be casted to Long)? because there is only one cast in there, and that casts TO Long, not FROM Long.

Comment: @GhostCat yes I'm certain. if it helps, the exception is still there when I don't try to cast

Comment: Well, to me this looks like either you have not provided the actual or full code, or your IDE has an anomaly and should simply be restarted in order to make the problem disappear. As Michael demonstrated, the posted code looks okay.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Intellij, but I'm also running tests on terminal, so I think it should be IDE-agnostic

Comment: I'm obligated to keep the rest of the code confidential :(

Comment: @emilyl You should ask someone in your company then. As I've shown, we cannot reproduce your problem so therefore we cannot answer your question.

Comment: Please note: without a [mcve] coming here and asking for help with "broken code" is pointless. We can only help with code bugs that we can look at. And when your code is confidential, then sit down and reduce it step by step to something that isn't confidential. Most often, alone the process of "peeling" problems down to their core is enough for you to identify the root cause yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From your error description, it looks like your method `purchase.getPurchaseId()` returns an object that is not of type `Long`. That's why you get a class cast exception. Instead of casting, you can build the Long object from the return value of this method, assuming it is either String or an integer type.

Replace

`.map(purchase -> (Long)purchase.getPurchaseId())`

with

`.map(purchase -> Long.valueOf(purchase.getPurchaseId()))`

Comment: `Long::new` is deprecated: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#Long-long-

Comment: `Long.valueOf(purchase.getPurchaseId())`

Comment: Thanks Michael and @YCF_L. Didn't realize that.

Comment: purchaseId is definitely a long. Long.valueOf doesn't work.

Comment: @emilyl, even if the purchaseId is `long`, it cannot be cast to `Long`. Long.valueOf will surely work. Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long)).